# How to set the hash without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery

I have this code to switch the content of a div, and need a hash in the url, but with the line `document.location.hash = a;` the page is going to reload. How can I set the hash without reloading the page?

```
$('.leftPass').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
    var b = 'chapters/' + a + '.php';
    $('#storyR').load(b);
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
    $('.leftAct').removeClass('leftAct').addClass('leftPass');
    $(this).removeClass('leftPass').addClass('leftAct');
    document.location.hash = a;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`location.hash` is correct. Changing it will not reload the page, ever. Is `.leftPass` a link by any chance? If yes, call `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler. `e` should be the first argument of the function:

```
$('.leftPass').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```